# Wrap from X to Y items using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

http://jsbin.com/uxepap/17/edit

How do I wrap **all links** from the third to the last **with one** `<span class="wrap"></span>`?

Try to make fixes, if it works, links would be on the red background with padding.

**Note:** it should be wrapper inside `a_items` var and just then showed by `.html();`

**By now, there is no working solution.**

Comment: Your demo has `display: block` on the links. You can't have block elements inside inline elements. This is an example of why it helps to post relevant code in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"should be wrapper inside `links` var and just then showed..."*? The elements are in the DOM. If you wrap the elements, they're being wrapped *in the DOM*, irrespective of the variable. There should be no reason to use `.html()` at all.

Comment: sorting make a clone of the links

Comment: so, there is a reason to use .html()

Comment: about display: block - there is no sense, its about css

Comment: So you don't want to wrap the elements. You want to make a copy of them that is wrapped. And no, you still wouldn't use `.html()`.

Comment: Yes it does make sense... because the block level elements will be kicked out of the inline elements by the browser... or at least won't display properly.

Comment: ...put this CSS on the page, and you can see them wrapped. `span {background: yellow; display: block}` http://jsbin.com/emequr/edit#javascript,html,live If you remove the `display: block` from `span`, suddenly the display changes.

Comment: @am not_i_am bye bro, I know css.

Comment: The point is that you are not being clear in your question about what you want. The solutions below display properly when the CSS is proper. If that's not the issue, and you actually want to wrap clones of the elements, instead of the elements themselves, then you should put that in the question. Seriously dude, you're the one looking for a solution. You should be accepting of comments. Your question is lacking information in its current form.

Comment: please see http://jsbin.com/uxepap/17/edit if its not clear, let me know

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what the desired outcome is, but is this close? http://jsbin.com/uxepap/18/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: or maybe this if you wanted to update the DOM with the sorted list before showing the wrap... http://jsbin.com/uxepap/19/edit#javascript,html,live

Comment: @Steve its better you explain *step by step* what you want. This question could be closed for being vague.

Comment: it should be showed **only** when we wrap links with span. Because there can be more than hundred links, not just ten. There should not be blink effect of the large list, which dissappears when script stop working

Comment: @am_not_i_am I'm talking about js, you're about CSS. Question is about JS, the solution is most important

Comment: @Steve: I've posted two JS solutions in the comments above. I was only talking about CSS originally because I couldn't figure out what the actual problem was. The wrap solutions below were working, but wouldn't display properly because of the CSS you posted in your original demo. Don't become impatient with people when you don't provide enough information to describe what you actually need. Everyone here is trying to help you... FREE OF CHARGE ...but you're making it extremely difficult.

Comment: Final demo, then I'm leaving: http://jsbin.com/uxepap/20/edit#javascript,html,live This one has almost 800 items. I get no "blink effect". If that was happening, it may be because you were treating the DOM as though it was a string of HTML. It isn't. It's a DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a:gt(2)').wrap('<span/>');
```

[**DEMO 1**](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/tkpQ6/1/)

or

```
var links = $('a');
var last = links.filter(':gt(2)');
last.wrap('<span/>');
```

[**DEMO 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/tkpQ6/2/)

**According to edit**

```
$('div a').map(function(index, item) {
    if(index > 2) {
        return $(item).wrap('<span class="wrap"/>').get(0)
    } else return $(item);
});
```

**[DEMO 3](http://jsfiddle.net/thecodeparadox/tkpQ6/7/)**

Comment: it should work with 'links' var

Comment: @Steve check `DEMO 2` with `links` var

Comment: links should be wrapped inside 'links' var, because we show them just after wrapping.

Comment: this should exist because of sorting

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tkpQ6/3/ it doesn't work this way, inside .wrap there is no links

Answer (score 0):

jQuery has [`slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) that filters your selection from selected start index to selected, optional end index.

[Here's a sample](http://jsbin.com/uxepap/14/edit).

```
var last = $('a')       //store them in last
    .slice(2)           //get third to last
    .remove()           //remove them from the DOM
    .wrap('<span>');    //wrap them in span
```

Comment: doesn't work http://jsbin.com/uxepap/11/edit

Comment: links should be wrapped inside 'links' var, we show them just after wrapping (replacing current links)

Comment: See the note please.. It should not be wrapped right away, instead of this we wrap them **inside var** and show when it needs to..

Comment: @Steve what do you mean by "not wrapped right away"? you can wrap them later using a function. Do you mean to say take out the 3rd to the last out the DOM and store them in a variable, wrapped and to be shown later?

Comment: please see http://jsbin.com/uxepap/17/edit, this won't work with my code

Answer (score 0):

`.wrap` wraps each element. Use [`wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) to wrap a set of elements:

```
last.wrapAll('<span></span>');
```

Comment: maybe I didn't understand what you're exactly trying to achieve

Answer (score 0):

```
var links = $('a').slice(2, $('a').length);
    links.wrap('<span/>');
```

Comment: the end index of slice is optional and defaults to the end

Comment: it should be wrapped **inside var**, not right away

Comment: @Steve: That makes no sense. The elements are currently in the DOM. How can you have them wrapped only from a variable reference without actually wrapping them in the DOM?

Comment: if there is no sense, why it doesn't work? example?

Comment: @Steve: Most of the answers here do work. Did you bother to read the first comment I left under your question?

Comment: there're all don't work, see updated question and example http://jsbin.com/uxepap/17/edit